# Why do we need vertex shader in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader

As far as I understand, the color of a pixel is determined by the fragment shader. Why do we need a vertex shader then? Is there anything a fragment shader cannot do (or cannot easily do) but a vertex shader can do (easily)?

Comment: You would find an answer in google if you tried. How do you tell the fragment shader which pixels are to be colored?

Comment: @aslg Thank you for your attention. I have been googling for hours but still cannot find an answer. I understand in the current structure you have to specify some transformation in vertex shader, but my question is why do we need that step? Why can't we just do the matrix multiplication in our program and simplify the pipeline to a single shader?

Comment: Because it will be terribly slow to transform larger meshes on the cpu?

Comment: There are multiple steps in the renderind pipeline aside from the Shaders. First, because the GPU already does most of the work for you and there's absolutely no reason you'd want to make that code yourself. Second, you don't need to simplify shaders for no reason - they are there to be used and there isn't much to gain from moving your multiplications back to the CPU. If you skip the vertex shader, then in your application you would have to create a number of textures with information on which pixels are to be drawn, depth, etc - which happens in the background already.

Comment: @aslg Thank you for the answer. Now I understand why it is needed. But the other question is why is it called a "shader"? If all its use is to transform vertices then why it is not called a "transformer"?

Comment: To add to that: On a modern graphiccard there are 5 shader stages, not just 2.

Comment: @BDL Thank you for the information. I will try to look into that after I have a better understanding of the whole pipeline.

Comment: You're worrying too much about semantics. "Vertex" because it processes vertices. "Shader" because it's a GPU program and belongs to the rendering/shading pipeline. Don't think too hard about it. Just because you've used the Vertex Shader exclusively foe transforms doesn't mean that's all it does. Be careful with the assumptions you make with lack of information ;)

Comment: @aslg That is actually what my original question was. I would like to know is there anything a vertex shader can do about "colors" but a fragment shader cannot do? I mean there must be a reason for the naming.

Comment: It's not about can and can't do. Yes there are things the Vertex Shader can do that the Fragment Shader can't, obviously. The Vertex Shader prepares your primitives to be used by the Fragment Shader later. The amount of data available to you in the Fragment Shader is determined back in the Vertex Shader. Also, environment mapping, among other rendering techniques, require the use of the Vertex Shader. I don't understand why you're so set in blaming the Vertex Shaders, perhaps you oughta follow more tutorials and learn by experience.

Comment: @aslg Thank you for the details. I will definitely have a look into environmental mapping. I am not blaming the vertex shader. It's just my way of learning things always first comes to the question "why do we need such a thing". Now at least one clear reason is "doing transformation in CPU is slow". But I still can't quite understand why it is named a "shader". Maybe I will understand after looking at environment mapping

Comment: It was simply an example of a technique that needs the Vertex Shader, that's all. And again, you're thinking too hard about semantics and it looks like you didn't read my other comment. It seems I can't help you, but here's a useful link to help you learn: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/

Comment: @aslg That's actually exactly what I was looking for: the existence of an example that needs the vertex shader (other than doing transformation fast.) I am looking at some environment mapping tutorial now and am finding it very helpful in my understanding of the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I still can't quite understand why it is named a "shader".

Because that's what programs executed as part of the rendering process are called. The [Renderman interface specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RenderMan_Interface_Specification) was one of the first programmable rendering processes, and [they called all of their programmable elements "shaders"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader#History), even though they didn't all compute colors.

And therefore, "shader" has become the term used for describing any such program.

Vertex shaders convert vertex data, creating a 1:1 mapping from input vertices to output vertices. Fragment shaders operate on [fragments](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment). An FS invocation has *no control* over *where* it will be executed. They are generated in the location that the rasterizer says they go, and the FS has no way to affect this.

By contrast, a vertex shader has complete control over where the vertices will go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I should think of the word shader as a completely new word unrelated to shade then.